# How to disable rotation in ios9?

Tags: ios, rotation, ios9

I want to disable my app's rotation, which is worked in iOS 9. I've tried

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
// Return YES for supported orientations
return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
}

- (NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}

- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation

NSNumber *value = [NSNumber numberWithInt:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft];
[[UIDevice currentDevice] setValue:value forKey:@"orientation"];
```

but no one works. Who knows?

Comment: you can even do it in xcode settings.

Comment: You can do with "Supported interface orientations" key in plist file.

Comment: It works. Many thanks.

Comment: What was the problem?

Comment: Your approach works. Please write an answer so I can adopt it.

Comment: @Caesar :- Please check my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
    </array>
```

Add above key in Plist file and add orientation based on your requirement.

I have added one for example.

Answer (score 1):

This should work from iOS 6 on upwards, but I've only tested it on iOS 8. Subclass UINavigationController and override the following methods:

```
- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
    return NO;
}
```

Or ask the visible view controller

```
- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation {
    return self.visibleViewController.preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
    return self.visibleViewController.shouldAutorotate;
}
```

and implement the methods there.

Comment: Change the "Device Orientation" key in General settings has worked.

Comment: but u can use for perticular view orientation.

Answer (score 1):

works like this:
write this in the ViewController.m

-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{ return NO; }

tried in Xcode 7.2, iOS 9.2, iPhone 6s Plus.